# Is it possible to have <DOCTYPE> inside <script>?

Tags: html, syntaxhighlighter

Is it possible to have `<DOCTYPE>` definition inside <`script>` tag in an HTML page?

I get an error that **A DOCTYPE is not allowed in content** .

Could someone tell me if I should be getting any such error for that?

Comment: Do you mean inside a string, like `var s = "<DOCTYPE>";` or literally just `<script><DOCTYPE> ... </script>`?  If the latter, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, assuming that you're referring to the [Document Type Declaration instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration), then it must start with `<!`, as in `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @Daniel: The error that I am getting is at line number 28 of https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/src/a8771a7fc81d/tests/theme_tests.html.

Comment: @Daniel: http://programatori.evonet.ro/images/1308360109285/doctype.jpg

Comment: @skip: That code is **wrong**.  HTML documents do not get nested inside `<script>` tags.  That is incorrect in any version of HTML.  The fact that it's from a file that's part of the tests of a syntax highlighting program indicates to me that it's an intentionally wrong sample designed to torture-test the syntax highlighter, not a code sample to emulate.

Answer (score 2):

Your doctype should be at the top of your document. Why do you want to put it anywhere else?

Comment: The file where I have it is a part of syntaxhighlighter 3.0.83. The name of the file is theme_tests.html. Here is the link for it, https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/src/a8771a7fc81d/tests/theme_tests.html. I am using syntaxhighlighter in my application and the thing is that I a getting the desired result on the page of my application on chrome but firefox is not displaying what chrome is displaying.

Comment: @Everyone: Many thanks for all the responses. The problem I was getting in my application was because of something very silly I was doing. I've got the problem resolved. It had nothing to do with DOCTYPE. All I ever knew about DOCTYPE was that in case of HTML it tells you the kind of HTML to be used in the document and for XML it tells you about the constraints on the structure of an XML. Many thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing it (with `<script type="text/plain">`) is fairly dangerous, but whatever you want to accomplish there can be fixed with CDATA:

`<script type="text/plain">`**`<![CDATA[`**

`(Your document)`
**`]]>`**`</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Your question forces me to assume that you better understanding of what a doctype is, this link might help: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

Comment: The error that I am getting is at line number 28 of https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/src/a8771a7fc81d/tests/theme_tests.html. I am just using syntaxhighlighter and all was well before i installed firefox 4 and jquerywtp1.10 plugin to my eclipse 3.5 IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind doctype is a browser instruction, not actual html. Therefore having it anywhere but the top is a bit odd, but more importantly it won't do anything.

Comment: @Lainlwakura: The error that I am getting is at line number 28 of https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/src/a8771a7fc81d/tests/theme_tests.html.